# Shell, test of unknown directories

Tags: shell

I have a really simple question about the command `test`.
I would like to know if at least the name of one directory begin by two digits (e.g. `09_test`).

I tried this command but it gives me nothing good : `test -d "[0-9][0-9]*" ; echo $?` or `test -d [0-9][0-9]* ; echo $?`.

Someone to help me please? :)

Comment: Well I have found a solution with the `find`command.
The problem is that the `$?` returns `0`even if no directory exists... : `find . -type d -name "[0-9][0-9]*" ; echo $?`

Comment: What system do you use? `Linux`, `BSD`, `Solaris`?

Comment: I am on a Linux system.

Comment: Do you have to use test or find? ls -d -- */ | grep '^[0-9][0-9]' will list all folders that starts with two digits.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I found another way to do that :

```
directory=`find [0-9][0-9]* -type d | tail -1`
if [ -d "$directory" ]; then
  #action
else
  #nothing
fi
```